# How can I make an http POST request from dart with authentication?

Tags: flutter, http, dart, flutter-http

I'm trying to do a post, to create a user, but in a simple way. I do need to use authentication, so I'm passing the token in the header, as I would do in the GET request. But I'm not sure why I'm receiving the error "400 - Bad Request".

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

{...}

Future test() async {
    Response response = await post('https://access.altaviu.com/Data/api/Account/Register',
        body: jsonEncode({
          "Email": "useruser@gmail.com",
          "Password": "QWERTY1234!",
          "ConfirmPassword": "QWERTY1234!",
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${UserAccountData.token}',
        });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('SUCCESSFUL TEST');
    } else {
      print('ERROR IN THE TEST ${response.statusCode} - ${response.reasonPhrase}');
    }
  }
```

I'm using the library (or package) "http: 0.12.0+2"

Comment: did you try printing the token ?

Comment: Are You sure about that, you are using bearer authentication for user creating, not basic auth?

Comment: Normally when the route is protected with token and it's not validated you will receive a 401 status code. WIth 400 could be that you are missing some field, but I'm not sure hows the back-end..

Comment: @KrishBhanushali I did and it's there

Comment: @xahid_rocks I did check and it is bearer

Comment: @Ayad I see, I'll check if maybe I should be sending a parent map, like ```{user: {Email: <>}}```